# 3 Parcheesi Use Cases Not Covered in the Rules - Help!

Tags: parcheesi

I have 3 use cases that I need help on to solve a family debate since none of these are covered in Parcheesi rules.  I would love it if someone can give a definitive answer:

1. If another player has one of their pawns on your entry (safe) space, and you roll a 5 to get one of your pawns out while they are there, does the other player get bumped, or do you both sit on that space together?
2. Same situation as above, but when you have one of your pawns on your entry (safe) space and another player has one of their pawns and you roll a 5 to get another one of your pawns out, does the other player get bumped?
3. If you have 2 of your pawns (a blockade) on your entry space and you roll a 5 on one die and another number on the other die (let's say a 3 for this case), can you move one of the existing pawns on your entry space 3 spaces FIRST to "make room" to use the 5 to get another pawn out?  Or do you have to use the 5 for something else?   We have a "house rule" that if you have a blockade of 2 of your pawns on the entry space and then you roll any 5's, you can't use them because we say that 5's for entering a pawn always have to be the first thing you do on a turn if you get them.

Since there are no specific rules in the Parcheesi game to cover the above, how can we substantiate your answers?  Thank you all so much.  Looking forward to your responses!

Answer (score 4):

1. They get bumped. Covered in [the rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parcheesi):

> A piece may not be placed on a safe space (generally colored light blue) if it is occupied by an opponent's piece.[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parcheesi) The exception is the safe space used when a piece leaves its nest — a single piece occupying such a safe space is sent back to its nest when an opponent's piece leaves the nest and occupies the space.[3]

2. Can't happen (see above)
3. Yes, you can move one of the existing pawns on your entry space 3 spaces FIRST to "make room" to use the 5 to get another pawn out. Covered in the rules:

> In the case of a non-doubles roll, a player may move one or two pieces, either one piece by each of the numbers on the two dice or one piece by the total. If no move is possible, the turn is forfeited.[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parcheesi)

Comment: 100% agree.   For #3, you can definitely move one of your players forward, and then the second pawn can enter.  There is **not** a rule that the "5 to enter" must be done first.